# Отображение на карте объектов

Tags: карты, ruby, gps

Нужно написать на Ruby ооооочень маленький сайт, но его особенностью будет карта: к примеру есть город Днепродзержинск и я на сайте устанавливаю карту от Google (или любую другую) и мне нужно указать на ней объекты, а объекты эти - люди, у которых имеется GPS. Так вот, человек передвигается по улице Карла-Маркса и мне нужно на карте отображать, что он передвигается по такой то улице. Вот собственно и задача. Есть хоть какие то варианты?

Comment: При чём здесь руби? И вопрос в чём?

Comment: Всё не так просто. Помимо приложения на руби вам нужно ещё написать приложение для мобильных устройств оснащённых GPS, чтобы они взаимодействовали с вашим сервером.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать Goolge Maps API в связке с Ruby: [View Your GPS Tracklogs in Google Maps](http://google-dox.net/O.Reilly-Google.Maps.Hacks/0596101619/googlemapshks-CHP-4-SECT-10.html), если наличие логотипа Google не является критичным.